# django-rest-framework customize serializer's output

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

With the below model and serializer:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class PersonSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name',)
```

I get:

```
[
   {"name": "Jon"},
   {"name": "Joe"},
   {"name": "Jim"}
]
```

How can I customize the serializer so that it outputs something like this:

```
{
  "out": [
    {"name": "Jon"},
    {"name": "Joe"},
    {"name": "Jim"}
  ],
  "message": "success"
}
```

Here `message` is built at runtime, otherwise I could have hard-coded it in JSONRenderer.

Comment: You should write custom Renderer class. Look Custom renderers [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really specified what type of control do you need over this message or where you want to be able to define it (on the serializer level, view level?).

You can always override the dispatch method like this (`MySimpleView` view class):

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(MySimpleView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    data = {}
    data['out'] = response.data
    data['message'] = "My message"

    response.data = data

    return response
```

I assume you want to control your custom message depending on the response status, so this seems like a perfect place, since the dispatch method returns the response itself.

So now just make it into a nice mixin and reuse it in you views..

But if you don't need the response status, then custom renderer is the way to go.